# 'StackExchange.Redis.ITransaction' does not contain a definition for 'StringSetAsync'

Tags: .net, transactions, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using transaction on Redis & using StackExchange.Redis provider.

I have a big batch of StringSetAsync operations for transaction.

And I've got an error during using StringSetAsync:

RuntimeBinderException was caught

'StackExchange.Redis.ITransaction' does not contain a definition for 'StringSetAsync'

StackTrace:

at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ITransaction , String , Object )
   at Repository.RedisDatabaseContextBase.SetRecord(IBasicRedisEntity redisEntity, Boolean isNewRecord)

====

## Added:

Here is example of code which reflect problem. Marc was right, it's all about **dynamic**.

```
try
{
  ConnectionMultiplexer cm = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6380,allowAdmin=true");
  var db = cm.GetDatabase();

  ITransaction transaction = db.CreateTransaction();

  dynamic pp = new byte[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  transaction.StringSetAsync("test", pp);

  if (transaction.Execute())
  {
    Console.Write("Committed");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.Write("UnCommitted");
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: RuntimeBinderException suggests you are using `dynamic` - is that correct?

Comment: No, I'm using generics. But at the end it still simply: transaction.StringSetAsync(key, value); // error

Comment: I hate to say it, but the mention of `CallSite` like this: **strongly suggests** `dynamic` is in play here - in which case, yes: it will fail for several scenarios (explicit implementation, for example). Do you have an example of the code where this is happening? Including the types of any variables (i.e. if you have `obj.StringSetAsync(...)`, what is `obj`?)

Comment: Yes, my bad. Please review my edited post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some ways it is correct: there is no overload that takes `byte[]`. There is one that takes `RedisValue`, but that *isn't the same thing*. `dynamic` method resolution can be glitchy - both for explicit interface implementations and conversion operators: both apply here!

I would suggest:

```
object pp = new byte[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

if(pp is byte[])
    transaction.StringSetAsync("test", (byte[])pp);
else if (pp is string)
    transaction.StringSetAsync("test", (string)pp);
else if (pp is RedisValue)
    transaction.StringSetAsync("test", (RedisValue)pp);
else
    throw new NotSupportedException(
        "Value is not usable: " + pp.GetType().FullName);
```

An alternative might be:

```
dynamic pp = new byte[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
transaction.StringSetAsync("test", (RedisValue)pp);
```

This *should work in theory*, but is still a bit unnecessary IMO.

Comment: This work in practice too, and I agree with you: better check the casting to prevent errors.